# disadvantages of generating keys at client side

Tags: arangodb

At inserting documents, if the key is generated at client-side. does it slow down the writes on a single machine or cluster?

I ask because i think server-side generated keys are sure to be unique and doesn't need to be checked for uniqueness. 
However what are the disadvantages or things to remember when generating keys on client side?(in single machine, sharding, master-master replication which is coming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating keys on the client-side should not have any notable performance impact for ArangoDB. ArangoDB will parse the incoming JSON anyway, and will always look for a `_key` attribute in it. If it does not exist, it will create one itself. If it exists in the JSON, it will be validated for syntactic correctness (because only some characters are allowed inside document keys). That latter operation only happens when a `_key` value is specified in the JSON, but its impact is very likely negligible, especially when compared to the other things that happen when documents are inserted, such as network latency, disk writes etc.

Regardless of whether a user-defined `_key` value was specified or not, ArangoDB will check the primary index of the collection for a document with the same key. If it exists, the insert will fail with a unique key constraint violation. If it does not exist, the insert will proceed. As mentioned, this operation will always happen. Looking for the document in the primary index has an amortized complexity of O(1) and should again be negligible when compared to network latency, disk writes etc. Note that this check will always happen, even if ArangoDB generates the key. This is due to the fact that a collection may contain a mix of client-generated keys and ArangoDB-generated keys, and ArangoDB must still make sure it hasn't generated a key that a client had also generated before.

In a cluster, the same steps will happen, apart from that the client will send an insert to a coordinator node, which will need to forward the insert to a dbserver node. This is independent of whether a key is specified or not. The `_key` attribute will likely be the shard key for the collection, so the coordinator will send the request to exactly one dbserver node. If the `_key` attribute is not the shard key for the collection because it a different shard key was explicitly set, then user-defined keys are disallowed anyway.

Summary so far: in terms of ArangoDB there should not be relevant performance differences between generating the keys on the client side or having ArangoDB generate them.

The advantages and disadvantages of generating keys in the client application are, among others:

`+` client application can make sure keys follow some required pattern / syntax that's not guaranteed by ArangoDB-generated keys and has full control over key creation algorithm (e.g. can use tenant-specific keys in multi-tenant application)

`-` client may need some data store for storing its key generator state (e.g. id of last generated key) to prevent duplicates (also after a restart of the client application)

`-` usage of client-side keys are disallowed when different shard keys are used in cluster mode

Comment: perfect answer helped so much. just one question, can ArangoDB guarantee server-side generated keys being alphabetically ordered(since key are strings)? or i should go with client-side generated keys

Comment: The default keys it generates consist of numeric digits only. They are generated from an ever-increasing integer sequence. This sequence is not guaranteed to be contiguous (e.g. 3 subsequently generated keys may be `"42"`, `"9899593"` and `"139492494"`). Which exact key comes next is not predictable. Note that keys in ArangoDB are always strings, so the above keys will sort as `"139492492"` < `"42"` < `"9899593"`.

Comment: Please also note that document keys (the values of `_key`) are used to efficiently look up documents via the primary index, which is an unsorted hash index. Looking up a single document via its key has amortized O(1) complexity. However, the hash index can't be used to sort the keys. Sorting the `_key` values in a collection will therefore always require a full collection scan and will be expensive (regardless if client-generated or not)!